# Cannot setstate in nested axios post request in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, rxjs

I am trying to access the res.data.id from a nested axios.post call and assign it to 'activeId' variable. I am calling the handleSaveAll() function on a button Click event. When the button is clicked, When I console the 'res.data.Id', its returning the value properly, but when I console the 'activeId', it's returning null, which means the 'res.data.id' cannot be assigned. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance

```
const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {}, [activeId]);

const save1 = () => {
      axios.get(api1, getDefaultHeaders())
        .then(() => {
          const data = {item1: item1,};

          axios.post(api2, data, getDefaultHeaders()).then((res) => {
            setActiveId(res.data.id);
            console.log(res.data.id); // result: e.g. 10
          });
      });
};

const save2 = () => {
  console.log(activeId); // result: null
};

const handleSaveAll = () => {
  save1();
  save2();

  console.log(activeId); // result: again its still null
};

return (
  <button type='submit' onClick={handleSaveAll}>Save</button>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, like in your example, the `console.log` function runs before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(activeId);
}, [activeId);
```

The callback will run every time the state value changes and only after it has finished changing and a render has occurred.

---

### Edit:

Based on the discussion in the comments.

```
const handleSaveSections = () => {
   // ... Your logic with the `setState` at the end.
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (activeId === null) {
      return;
   }
   save2(); // ( or any other function / logic you need )
}, [activeId]);

return (
   <button onClick={handleSaveSections}>Click me!</button>
)
```

Comment: Actually I need to use the 'activeId' in another function right after its been assigned from the axios post call. I tried putting it in the useEffect callback, but when I call the 'activeId' from another function, its still returning it as a null.

I edited the question by the way and explained in a better way so that the issue can be undrestood better.

Comment: The edit you've made is exactly the same example. You are still calling the second function before the state has updated. As mentioned, `useEffect` runs it's callback only **after** the state has finished mutating. Therefor, if you need to use the updated value of the state for some function, do it inside of the `useEffect`.

Comment: but I am calling the handleSaveAll() function on a button Click event. how can I fix that?

Comment: I don't see the issue here. You run `handleSaveAll()` on a button click event, and it will ultimately set the state (even though it doesn't reflect the change right away in the `console.log`).. The question is, what is the desired flow here? i.e. - what do you need to do with the state after it has been set?

Comment: In-fact, let's make this simpler and look at your example. You have `save1()` and `save2()`. `save1()` sets the state, then `save2()` needs to use the new state value. So what you can do is call `save1()` on a click event as you've mentioned, and then run `save2()` inside of the `useEffect`, which should contain the updated value.

Comment: Also edited the question to provide an example.

Comment: Tried your way, still the same

Comment: Does the recent edit you've made to your post reflect what you tried to do? If so, then it is incorrect. Please see the example I've provided, it is not the same thing.

Comment: I its the same code, I just removed some extra lines so that it could be read better. I also tried your way and used the useEffect() hook, but still its the same.

Comment: I just need to assign the value from 'res.data.id' to 'metricId' so that I can use it somewhere else in another function. Maybe you can give me a better solution than my existed code.

Comment: As mentioned before, one thing that is important to understand here is that the fact that the `console.log` shows the previous value, doesn't mean that it is actually the case. In all of the examples you provided you are trying it as if it is a synchronous action and you attempt to log to console right after it. **This will not work**. Hence, it is important to grasp how the state works and how to handle it. At this point I would suggest to go over the documentation for React with hooks.

Comment: Here is a very simple example. https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-easley-6e79qb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

As the setState is a async task, you will not see the changes directly.
If you want to see the changes after the axios call, you can use the following code :

```
       axios.post(api2, data, getDefaultHeaders())
        .then((res) => {
         setActiveId(res.data.id)
         console.log(res.data.id) // result: e.g. 10
         setTimeout(()=>console.log(activeId),0);
      })
```

```
useEffect(() => {
}, [activeId]);

const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);

const save1 = () => {
    const handleSaveSections = async () => {
        activeMetric &&
            axios.get(api1, getDefaultHeaders()).then(res => {
                if (res.data.length > 0) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        text: 'Record already exists',
                        icon: 'error',
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    const data = {
                        item1: item1,
                        item2: item2
                    }

                    axios.post(api2, data, getDefaultHeaders())
                        .then((res) => {
                            setActiveId(res.data.id)
                            console.log(res.data.id) // result: e.g. 10
                        })
                }
            });
    }
handleSaveSections()
}

const save2 = () => {
    console.log(activeId);   //correct result would be shown here
}

const handleSaveAll = () => {
    save1();
    save2();
}
 
return (
    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSaveAll}>Save</button>
)
```

Comment: Actually I need to use the 'activeId' in another function right after its been assigned from the axios post call. I tried putting it in the useEffect callback, but when I call the 'activeId' from another function, its still returning it as a null.

I edited the question by the way and explained in a better way so that the issue can be undrestood better.

Comment: You should call handleSaveSections function which u have created it in save1 function. You are not calling it right now.

Comment: I did it, still null. I edited the question and edit the code as well so that it could be seen more clear.

Comment: How do u know that your second api is running properly?

Comment: It is running without an issue, because if u see, when I console the 'res.data.id', it returns the value from the api response. I just need to assign the value from 'res.data.id' to 'metricId' so that I can use it somewhere else in another function